# Casting a variable of type 'Object' to a type 'Class'

Tags: java, reflection

The Scenario is:

```
Object anObj="7";
Object anotherObject="7.77";
Class aClass=Class.forName("java.lang.Integer");
Class anotherClass=Class.forName("java.lang.Double");
```

I want to typecast `anObj` to `aClass`-type and `anotherObject` to `anotherClass`-type.

The values for Class variables `aClass` and `anotherClass` may vary, so i dont want them to be casted using the *`parseXXX()`* methods...

I tried using `aClass.cast(anObj);` but it throws `InstantiationException`
Can anybody help me?

Thanks in advance.
ArK.!

Comment: Those typecasts will fail because the objects are strings - you can't *cast* a string to an `Integer` or a `Double`. That's why `cast` fails; you need to stop thinking in terms of casts, and start thinking in terms of calling constructors or methods to perform the string conversion.

Comment: Jon is right; you can only downcast (like from Object to Integer), if the Object actually is an Integer, but for some reason is in an Object variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before casting them to aClass and anotherClass, you need to cast anObj and anotherObject to respective classes

```
aClass.cast(Integer.parseInt((String) anObj));
anotherClass.cast(Double.parseDouble((String) anotherObject));
```

Answer (score 1):

`anObj` and `anotherObject` are `String` instances. Whatever is the target class, you can't just cast them, you need some method (like `Integer.parseInt()`) that will convert a String instance to the particular type.

You need some sort of convention for this to work (like "class must have a static `fromString(String)` method"), and then you can get to the conversion method using reflection.